# Need tricky idea to use JS variable in php

Tags: javascript, php

Need a tricky idea to use JS variable in PHP. Want to display the array value in tricky way.

```
<?php
$cars[0] = "Volvo";
$cars[1] = "BMW";
$cars[2] = "Toyota";
?>

var varCounter = 0;
var varName = function() {
    if (varCounter <= 2) {
        varCounter++;
        document.write("<?php echo $cars[varCounter]; ?>");
    } else {
        clearInterval(varName);
    }
};
```

Comment: this looks more like you want to use a PHP variable in JS - EDIT oh I see now. A simpler way might be to echo your PHP array to JS first, then you can use the varCounter variable.

Comment: Why don't you want to generate a js array from php array and insert it into the javascript? It could be easier, then using ajax.

Comment: @user4035 I think you are in the right way but am very new to php and JS. Could you please implement your idea here.

Comment: @AsimKrishnaDas user2864740 gave you the code in his answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following in which all the data is embedded in the JavaScript (HTML) when the PHP code runs on the server. Thus PHP never "sees" the JavaScript value, but the JS has access to all the possible PHP values.

The values (which are once again *embedded* in the PHP generated HTML) are supplied via [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) in a pretty package - JSON is ["close enough"](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset) to JS Object Literals for this to work reliably (json_encode without the JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE option is also immune to the linked quibble).

```html
<?php
    // Array values come from PHP
    $cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
?>

<script>
// Don't forget JSON_HEX_TAG when using this method!
var cars = <?php echo json_encode($cars, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>;
// Equivalent to the following with the above data, but in Real Life
// the data might come from a dynamic source or also be used in PHP.
// var cars = ["Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"];

// Now all the data is available to JavaScript, which can be treated as
// a normal JavaScript array.
var varCounter = 0;
var varName = function() {
    if (varCounter < cars.length) {
        // Do *not* use document.write after the document is closed
        alert(cars[varCounter]);
        varCounter++;
    } else {
        clearInterval(varName);
    }
};

// etc.
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use ajax, as javascript is a client language, when php is a server side language. php is executed before sending the page to the browser, then the javascript is renderer.

If you prefere you can generate the javascript with the php, the values will be printed inside the code. But you have to modify the javascript generation.

Comment: No you **don't** have to use ajax for this simple task as @user2864740 showed, if you know the values before the page is created, you can embed the PHP array to JS array easily

Comment: Yes but not at the moment of the javascript execution. as @user2864740 showed :) Read my answer, I let two solutions

Answer (score 3):

This is how an interval is created:

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(code, delay);
```

1. The variable `varName` is not an `intervalID`.
2. The parameter to `write` in `document.write('<?php echo $cars[varCounter]; ?>')` will not change at the front-end. It will simply print a static value ("Volvo" in this case).
3. You need to use AJAX to dynamically interact with your PHP back-end.