# Put php code inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have javascript code like this:

```
<script>
$("#ancbahan_add").click(function(){
 $('#tblbahan tr').last().after('');
});
</script>
```

And i want to put this php code:

```
<?php

echo "<select name='anggota'>";

$show=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_satuan ORDER BY id_satuan");
echo "<option value='belum milih' selected>-satuan-</option>";

while($w=mysql_fetch_array($show))
{
    echo "<option value=$w[satuan]>$w[satuan]</option>";        
}
    echo "</select>";

?>
```

inside `.after` **`('')`**, i completely had no idea how to do it, since i'm new in using javascript.

So i hope someone can give me some solution, Thanks.

Comment: Use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: You *don't* necessarily need "AJAX" or anything fancy to access "data from PHP". [Here is an answer I wrote, which may be applicable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281758/need-tricky-idea-to-use-js-variable-in-php/25281931#25281931). The big thing to note is that PHP executes on the server and it returns HTML. This HTML is parsed *after* the PHP executes and any JavaScript is also run *later*. However, the PHP (if it does not actually *require* a value from the JavaScript) can trivially emit JavaScript/JSON (or HTML) to be manipulated and/or consumed during the initial page fetch.

Answer (score 3):

If this content does not change, I would recommend you render the element on the page after the last `tr`, but just make sure the `<select>` element has the following attribute: `style="display: none;"`. Then you can just use the following javascript to show it:

```
$("#ancbahan_add").click(function(){
  $('#tblbahan tr').last().show();
});
```

I should say that it looks like you are going to have HTML that looks like this:

```
<table>
 <tr></tr>
 <select></select>
</table>
```

This HTML is invalid as the select should be inside a table cell.

Comment: well, i forgot to say this, but my javascript function is to add new table row dynamically, so `$('#tblbahan tr').last().after('');` function is to add new tr inside table, and the combobox is inside that tr, so when i click add, i want it to add new row plus the combobox..

Comment: Great! I would still recommend doing it like this unless the content changes. Just make sure the `tr` has the `display: none;` style.

Answer (score 2):

To make it cleaner I'd do something like this:

```
<?php
$select = "<select name='anggota'>";
$show=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_satuan ORDER BY id_satuan");
echo "<option value='belum milih' selected>-satuan-</option>";
while($w=mysql_fetch_array($show))
{
  $select .= "<option value=$w[satuan]>$w[satuan]</option>";
}
$select .= "</select>";
?>

<script>
$("#ancbahan_add").click(function(){
  $('#tblbahan tr').last().after('<?php echo $select; ?>');
});
</script>
```

EDIT: to add a row like you requested:

```
<script>
$("#ancbahan_add").click(function(){
  $('#tblbahan').append('<tr><?php echo $select; ?></tr>');
});
</script>
```

Comment: my javascript function is to add new table row dynamically, so $('#tblbahan tr').last().after(''); function is to add new tr inside table, and the combobox is inside that tr, so when i click add, i want it to add new row and the combobox(inside that new row). when i tried your code, my add function didn't working. --

Comment: So just add a '<tr>'...'</tr>' around the select.

Or do an append().

Comment: Well, i had no trouble with my add new row function, be it with append or last().after().

But when i add your code to my code (with last.after or with append), it make the add new row function didn't working..

Answer (score 0):

Just go ahead and paste the whole PHP snippet (including opening and closing `<?php ?>` tags) between the quotes `' '`. The PHP will run on the server and the correct values will appear in the javascript.

Comment: i've tried it, something like this : `$('#tblbahan tr').last().after('<tr><td><input type="text" name="kemasan2[]"><?php echo "<select name='anggota'>";$tampil=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_satuan ORDER BY id_satuan");echo "<option value='belum milih' selected>-satuan-</option>";while($w=mysql_fetch_array($tampil)){echo "<option value=$w[satuan]>$w[satuan]</option>";} echo "</select>";?></td></tr>');` , but what happened is my javascript completely didn't working, sorry my bad language.

Comment: Firstly, use the cleaner answer from @sitesbyjoe. Check the source code in the browser, and if the correct text appears in your javascript call then there's a problem with your javascript. To fix that we need to see a bit more of what your javascript should result in.

Comment: well, my javascript code function is to add new row in my table, so when i click add, it will add new tr inside the table, when i tried @sitesbyjoe code, my add function didn't working (didn't add new row or do anything), -_-

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#tblbahan tr').last().after(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "test.php"//php page url
    }).done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
)
```

Comment: Please don't post just code as an answer. Explain why this is better (if indeed it is).